# Irreducible polynomial $x^n - P(y)$ in field extension when $P(y)$ is not constant and not has repeated factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I'm very confused about how to prove the next statement. In class, we already know about the einsteins criterion and some tests of irreducibility but I don't remember any that taking into account the divisibility of the field characteristic. ( I rewrite the problem course I think it was badly redacted)

**Statement:** Let $k$ a field and $P(y) ∈ k[y]$ a polynomial which is not constant and not has repeated factors. Show that the polynomial $x^n - P(y)$ is irreducible in $k[x,y]$.

I don't really know even how to start so any help is welcome, Thank you in advance!

**Attempt:** I try by using Eisenstein's criterion to $x^n - P(y)$ as a polynomial with coefficients in $k[y]$ as a PID because remember that if F is a field then F[x] is a PID. But I really don't know how to use the criterion in a general case like P(y) like using the gcd? I don't get it.

Comment: Why delete the [previous question](/q/4252266) and post it verbatim again?

Comment: @user10354138 Yeah, I do it because the initial redaction was very confusing.